# Latest Ubuntu that supports my graphics card?

Tags: nvidia, hardware

Today I decided to dig up my old computer,  a Dell Dimension E521. I want to install Ubuntu on it and turn it into a media system,  with Kodi and Steam In-Home Streaming.  However,  with my bootable USB containing the latest Ubuntu, when ever I try to boot into the usb for installation,  I simply get a black screen with a white blinking underscore.

My specs are:
4GB DDR2
Nvidia Geforce 6150 LE
AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 4200+

What is the most recent version of Ubuntu that supports the latest Nvidia drivers for the 6150 LE?

Thank you a lot!

EDIT: Also, I want able to get the latest versions of OpenElec working,  I had to use an nvdia legacy version.

EDIT2: Is it possible that I accidentally deleted someone's answer? Sorry about that. And no, I can't even get to the live boot. Nothing works at all. Just a black screen with a blinking underscore...

Comment: You assume the different active ubuntu versions do not support the same hardware why exactly?

Comment: I'm new to Linux,  sorry

Comment: 1st thing to do is boot with options turned off. Like "nomodeset".

Comment: Not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card is listed as supported by the Nvidia proprietary driver version 304. As far as I know, this driver is available to all Ubuntu versions since 12.04.

If you cannot install Ubuntu itself, try "nomodeset" as has been suggested. In order to do that, when the installer starts up you either have a menu pop-up or you have a keyboard icon at the bottom letting you press a key to bring the menu up (depending on the version you have).

From within the menu, you have the option of "Trying without installing", actually "Installing", and a few other ones. Depending which specific version you have, setting "nomodset" can be done 2 ways. There's a "kernel parameters" line, get to it by pressing one of the F-keys and type "nomodeset" just before you see "splash" or "no splash". An alternative is to use a menu (F6 on most versions), highlight "nomodeset" and press space or enter.

"Trying without installing" is clunky with an older graphics card, your best bet is to actually install. Be advised that Nvidia support for older cards is a hair-pulling experience.

Once you have Ubuntu installed, you have 2 choices for drivers with nvidia cards. Package "nouveau" tends to be your best bet for Nvidia cards, but nouveau needs modeset, and if your system won't boot unless you use nomodeset, nouveau won't work for you. Try installing package "nvidia-304" or "nvidia-304-updates".

Comment: The problem is that when I select to boot into the Ubuntu USB, to install Ubuntu, it immediately brings me to a black screen with a white blinking underscore. That's it. I can't do anything else.

Comment: Make sure your  USB is bootable. Try it on a different laptop or PC, sometimes these things get corrupted.

Comment: What's a good program to do that? I've tried a couple of times with Rufus on Windows?

Thanks

Comment: There's no program for this: stick your USB in another laptop or PC and try to boot from it :)

Comment: Sorry, let me explain xD

What is a good program to create a bootable drive from Windows? I've been using Rufus. Sorry, I wasn't very clear.

Comment: Hmm... I managed to get my relatively new laptop to boot using the bootable USB. I booted with UEFI. Could this be a problem for the desktop? There's no option for UEFI on the desktop..?

Comment: Yes, it is a problem, the problem actually. Rufus has two option, UEFI/GTP and BIOS/MBR. You need the former for UEFI enabled hardware such your laptop and the latter for older hardware. With Rufus you can't have both.

Comment: I think what @CelticWarrior is saying is that you need to make a fresh copy of your USB installer, this time select BIOS/MBR.

Comment: Exactly. For old non-UEFI hardware that option is required using Rufus.

Comment: I'll give that a when I get home from school.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: Okay,  so I used the MBR and BIOS or UEFI option,  still,  a black screen without even a white underscore. ..